# If encapsulation is properly designed in the class

Tags: java, encapsulation

Is encapsulation is properly designed in this class? Example object instances with negative height and width values can or cannot exist?

```
import java.awt.Dimension; 
/** * Example class. The x and y values should never * be negative. 
*/ 
public class Example { 
    private Dimension d = new Dimension (0, 0); 
    public Example () {} 
    /** * Set height and width. Both height and width must be nonnegative * or an exception is thrown. */ 
    public synchronized void setValues (int height, int width) throws IllegalArgumentException { 
        if (height < 0 || width < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException(); 
        d.height = height; 
        d.width = width; 
    }

    public synchronized Dimension getValues() { // Passing member content by ref
        return d; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't enforce that. People can still alter the height and width values via the Dimension object you return in getValues() even though that violates the law of demeter principle.

```
Example example = new Example();
example.setValues(10, 5);
System.out.println(example.getValues()); // java.awt.Dimension[width=5,height=10]

Dimension dimension = example.getValues();
dimension.height = -1;
dimension.width = -1;
System.out.println(example.getValues()); // java.awt.Dimension[width=-1,height=-1]
```

From the docs:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Dimension.html#width

> public int width
>
> The width dimension; negative values can be used.

To overcome this a solution could be to return a deep clone of the Dimension object in getValues() to prevent changes to the original object using a library such as:
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/SerializationUtils.html#clone(java.io.Serializable)

```
public synchronized Dimension getValues() { 
    return SerializationUtils.clone(d); 
    // OR return new Dimension(d.width, d.height);
}
```

Comment: You don't need a library to make a deep clone: `return new Dimension(d);` does what you need.

Comment: @AndyTurner I agree a copy constructor would suffice in the current context. I suggested a library, because as objects become more complex a novice programmer might struggle creating an actual deep copy.

Comment: What you've basically said is "I know that OP only wants a nail in the wall to hang a picture, but I'll tell them about diggers, in case they ever need to build a house". Tell beginners about simple solutions first, so they don't assume they have to use complicated solutions to solve easy problems.

Comment: Thanks, I'll read the docs which You suggested and redesign the class.